# Rotated canvas sprite not drawing properly

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, transformation

First, sorry for my english. Said that: Recently I began to study JavaScript and like a way to consolidate what I learned I decided to make a simple video game with canvas and javascript: kind of Mortal Kombat demo, without library or game engine, just what I had learned until the moment. The problem with my little project is that when and move it or throw a punch with player2 (which is basically player1 rotated) the sprite becomes a mess, even when the code is exactly the same that for player1. I guess is related with rotating the context, but I can't figure it out. Here is the code [mortal kombat demo](https://github.com/kanonhian/mk-demo), along with basic instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I found this

```
that.context.translate(xPosition + frameWidth, yPosition + frameHeight);
that.context.rotate(180 * Math.PI / 180);
that.context.scale(1, -1);
that.context.translate( - (xPosition + frameWidth),  - (yPosition + frameHeight));
```

Then you clear the previous rendering in the new coordinates system which i am guessing is resulting in bits of the previous sprite not being cleared

To fix I would rewrite the function as (sorry forgot you had where using the object `that`)

```
// Clear the old image out (you should just be clearing the whole canvas every frame 
// with a background so you dont need to do this.
var oldYCoord = floor - previousHeight;
this.context.clearRect(xPosition, oldYCoord, previousWidth, previousHeight);
// Saving context only because I do not know what the current state is
this.context.save();
// Set the top left or right corner of the image
if (fliped) {
    this.setTransform(-1,0,0,1,xPosition + frameWidth,yPosition); // flip x axis and 
                                                                  // set origin to top right of image
}else{
    this.setTransform(1,0,0,1,xPosition,yPosition); // set origin to top right of image
}
// draw the image at the new origins
this.context.drawImage(that.image, 
    frameOriginX, frameOriginY, frameWidth, frameHeight, 
    0,0, frameWidth, frameHeight  // @ 0,0
);
// restore
this.context.restore();
// if you don't do any other transforms elsewhere then remove the save and restore and add the following lineHeight
// this.context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // restores default transform is quicker than save restore
```

I am guessing that will solve the problem.

BTW `180 * Math.PI / 180` when you multiply then divide by the same value they cancel each other out, `180/180 = 1` so the result is `Math.PI`

But you don't need to rotate just mirror along the x axis as is done in `context.setTranform(-1,0,0,1,x,y)` the first two values are the vector pointing in the direction of the x axis, the second two are the vector pointing along the y axis and the last two are the location of the origin. The values are always in canvas pixel coordinates when using setTransform, unlike `translate`,`rotate`,`scale`, and `transform` which are in the current transformed coordinate system

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the advices blindsman, were really usefull; what takes me to ask you about a full tutorial or book or bibiliography in general about the transformation matrix if you know.

Comment: @Krlos9108 unfortunately I do not know of any good learning resource for the transformation matrix.